# Simple texture blurred in Cycles render but not in Eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

When I render my scene in Eevee, all works well. But in Cycles, my textures are blurred and some details disappear, even with 1500 samples and no denoising. Can you help me please ?
Thanks :) !
[image: Render in Eevee]
[image: Render in Cycles]
[image: UV map of the floor in foreground]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). @Martynas is right, please add more details, perhaps your material setup and consider sharing your .blend file. Without that, it's just guessing :).

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys We don't want to scare new users away. If they haven't given enough information, suggest what they could add to improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

After several tests, I found the problem.

My file is a Sketchup import and the floor geometry is a bit special. As you can see the mesh has a thickness and a diagonal edge, and this one was like inside the mesh. By moving it up outside (I did it much more to illustrate on the picture), the mesh becomes more valid and the texture is correctly applied.

[image: bad mesh form sketchup import]